# Elixir app test configuration

Tags: elixir

I have a phoenix web app that uses redis for data storage. My config folder contains the following files:

*config.exs*

```
config :exredis,
  url: System.get_env("REDIS_URL") || "redis://redis:6379/0",
```

*test.exs*

```
config :exredis,
  url: "redis://redis:6379/1"
```

When I run tests from console using

```
mix test test/my_test.ex
```

the production instance of redis is used instead of test one.

I can make it work by running

```
REDIS_URL="redis://redis:6379/1" mix test test/my_test.exs
```

but how can I force it to use the test config automatically?

I run tests from console using `mix test test/my_test.exs`.

Comment: Did you add that code above this line in `config.exs`: `import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"`? Otherwise `test.exs` wouldn't be able to override it.

Comment: That's it! `import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"` wasn't at the bottom of `config.exs`. Moving it there fixed the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As clarified in comments, you had added that code below `import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"`.

`import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"` must remain at the bottom of `config.exs`, otherwise `test.exs` cannot override any config set in `config.exs` because it'll be evaluated before the config that are set after `import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"`.